# Grub legacy debian 10

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub

To make a long story short: I need to boot GRUB from a floppy in order to load a Debian 10 install.

GRUB2 is too big to fit on a floppy, so I wanted to use legacy grub. However I have no experience with it, and I'm not able to get the system booting.

I am using this floppy image: https://q4.github.io/bootgrub.html

I get a list with all the partitions on the harddrive, however only the Windows installation is bootable. When I try to boot Debian I get an error 13: Invalid or unsupported executable format.

I can boot just fine with grub2 installed on the hard drive, but I need to use a very specific bootloader on there which is not compatible with Linux (I've tried). My goal is to boot grub from floppy whenever I want to boot into Linux, and have the weird bootloader installed on my harddrive.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it myself. What worked in the end was removing grub2 completely, then installing grub-legacy and following this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GrubHowto/BootFloppy I got everything working.

To remove grub2 run sudo apt purge grub2 grub-pc.

I've never got it working manually, but by using grub in interactive mode (see tutorial above) it was a 5 minute process and worked out of the box!